Laravel Echo & Pusher status code 200 but frontend no notification
I’m trying to broadcast notifications via a private channel to my web application for users who are logged in. Here’s what I’ve done so far:
I set up Laravel Echo and Pusher.
When I test with php artisan tinker, I can see data in the debug console of Pusher-JS.
I checked Telescope, and the status for [post] /broadcasting/auth is 200.
However, despite all this, the frontend doesn’t display the notifications. Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this issue would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you so much~
I ensure that App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class is not commented.
(Laravel 11) .env:
BROADCAST_CONNECTION=pusher
AlertMenu.tsx:
       window.Pusher = Pusher;

        const echo = new Echo({
            broadcaster: 'pusher',
            key: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            cluster: "mt1",
            forceTLS: true,
        });

AlertEvent.php:
new PrivateChannel('project.'.$project_id.'.alerts');
BroadcastServiceProvider.php
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Broadcast;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class BroadcastServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     */
    public function boot(): void
    {
        Broadcast::routes();

        require base_path('routes/channels.php');
    }
}

channels.php
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Broadcast;

Broadcast::channel('App.Models.User.{id}', function ($user, $id) {

    return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
});

Broadcast::channel('project.{project_id}.alerts', function ($user, $project_id) {

    if($user->current_project_id == $project_id){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
});

I have also tried to add the controller and route to the web.php but the status code will change from 200 to 419,
web.php
Route::post('/broadcasting/auth', [PusherController::class, 'pusherAuth'])->middleware('auth');

PusherController:
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Pusher\Pusher;

class PusherController extends Controller
{
    public function pusherAuth(Request $request)
    {

        $user = auth()->user();
        $socket_id = $request['socket_id'];
        $channel_name = $request['channel_name'];
        $key = getenv('PUSHER_APP_KEY');
        $secret = getenv('PUSHER_APP_SECRET');
        $app_id = getenv('PUSHER_APP_ID');

        if ($user) {

            $pusher = new Pusher($key, $secret, $app_id);
            $auth = $pusher->socket_Auth($channel_name, $socket_id);

            return response($auth, 200);
        } else {
            header('', true, 403);
            echo "Forbidden";
            return;
        }
    }
}


